# Preventing the file to be downloaded on other device

Tags: java, android

I want to create an paid app which has a file which can be downloaded.If users buys my application and downloads the file.I want disable the user from transferring that file any other device.Some kind of Cyptography i guess.I have searched everywhere but no luck.Please guys help me to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You would either have to hack the Android operating system in order to do that, or you would need to make a program that keeps checking what eachfile the user opens is.